# Static IP and DNS in Debian 9

Tags: networking, configuration

I have configure my DNS in resolv.conf but it is clearing anytime the system reboots. Pls how do i configure DNS on Debian 9 to remain after reboot.
thanks

I but the line dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 1.1.1.1 in the interfaces but not working, also I but the same line in resolv.conf but clear after system reboot

Comment: you shouldn't be editing your `resolv.conf`. (it is stated on the first line of the file) Can you add some information about your installation? Is it a desktop or server installation, and does it use systemd/networkd/network-manager?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file /etc/resolv.conf contains the line

1. `# Generated by NetworkManager`

NetworkManager's configuration can be set to avoid the flushing.